# Grab selected values from Bootstrap SelectPicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a script that uses [the Bootstrap SelectPicker plug-in](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/bootstrap-select) to choose my favourite coffees.

Once the form is submitted, I'd like to store the values selected and send to `addCoffee.php?coffee=${coffee}`. How do I do this?

**HTML:**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.13.1/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">

  <div class="row">

    <!-- Multiple Item Picker -->
    <div class="jumbotron">
        <h2>Multiple Item Picker</h2>
        <select id="coffee" class="selectpicker show-menu-arrow" 
                data-style="form-control" 
                data-live-search="true" 
                title="-- Select your coffee --"
                multiple="multiple">
        <option data-tokens="Espresso">Espresso</option>
        <option data-tokens="Americano">Americano</option>
        <option data-tokens="Mocha">Mocha</option>
        <option data-tokens="Capuccino">Capuccino</option>
        <option data-tokens="Affogato">Affogato</option>
        <option data-tokens="Long Black">Long Black</option>
        <option data-tokens="Macchiato">Macchiato</option>
        </select>

        <p></p><input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"></p>

    </div><!--.jumbotron-->

  </div><!--.row-->

</div><!--.container-->

<script>
$('#coffee').selectpicker();

$('#submit').on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $('#coffee').selectpicker('refresh');

    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: `addCoffee.php?coffee=${coffee}`,

    success: function (response) {
        alert("Successfully submitted Coffee for review.");
    }
    });

})
</script>
```

Comment: If you want to use URL parameters, you need to use `GET` instead of `POST`. You might also need to specify the `dataType` and `contentType` for your ajax request.

Comment: That part actually works fine so far. It's more the `coffee` variable. It sends the data looking like `[object HTMLSelectElement]` rather than the items selected. How do I get around that?

Comment: You need to specify `contentType` to the correct type, so that the server knows what type of data you are sending (i.e. what your coffee variable looks like).

Comment: Thanks @Decay42, for this example, what should I push the `contentType` as?

Comment: Can't see where your coffee variable is coming from, so I can't know what kind of `contentType` it is. Just grab the `value` from your select element an pass it as a string, then the default `contentType` of `application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8` should be fine.

Comment: @Decay42 'Coffee' variable would contain all the items selected in the picker :-)

Comment: Okay, so I've added that in, but my console still looks like: `addCoffee.php?coffee=[object%20HTMLSelectElement]` :(

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous"><script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.13.1/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
            <h2>Multiple Item Picker</h2>
            <select id="coffee" class="selectpicker show-menu-arrow" 
                    data-style="form-control" 
                    data-live-search="true" 
                    title="-- Select your coffee --"
                    multiple="multiple">
                <option data-tokens="Espresso">Espresso</option>
                <option data-tokens="Americano">Americano</option>
                <option data-tokens="Mocha">Mocha</option>
                <option data-tokens="Capuccino">Capuccino</option>
                <option data-tokens="Affogato">Affogato</option>
                <option data-tokens="Long Black">Long Black</option>
                <option data-tokens="Macchiato">Macchiato</option>
            </select>

            <p></p><input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"></p>
</div><!--.container-->

<script>
$('#submit').on("click", function(e) {
    var val = $('#coffee').val();
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: `addCoffee.php`,
        data: {"myData":val},
        success: function (response) {
            alert("Successfully submitted Coffee for review.");
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for this. In my `addCoffee.php` script, I have `var_dump($_POST);` and it gives me: `array(1) { ["undefined"]=> string(0) "" }`

Comment: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token var`

Comment: sorry sorry it should  `val` and i have updated answer. now in `php` file `var_dump($_POST['myData']);`   and you will get your selected values